# Постпозитивный номинатив?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Она его накормила, напоила и спать уложила. Короче говоря, простая деревенская женщина.

*Простая деревенская женщина* — это постпозитивный номинатив? Какое влияние у оборота *короче говоря*?

Comment: *Какого влияние оборота короче говоря?* - на что влияние?! Уточните, что именно вы хотели спросить. По "постпозитиву" - вопрос понятен, но это терминологические заморочки, вряд ли мы тут к единому мнению придем. Термин "постпозитив" более известен по английскому языку, но там он означает нечто совершенно иное, к русскому вообще не применимое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> это постпозитивный номинатив?

Всё-таки, думаю, что да. Хотя и с оговорками.
Если идти по Валгиной, то получается вообще почти любой именительный падеж (по крайней мере не в функции явного подлежащего в двусоставном предложении) должен быть либо препозитивом, либо постпозитивом. Методом исключения выводим постпозитив.

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-025.htm

Но, с другой стороны, постпозитив должен так или иначе относиться ко всей предыдущей конструкции, а не к её части. И вот с этим тут не очень понятно.

Насчет "короче говоря" - ну не знаю, не похоже, что вводная конструкция может повлиять на синтаксическую роль. Хотя это тоже бабка надвое сказала, нет тут исчерпывающей теории, мне во всяком случае таковая неизвестна.